# Reference on properties of binary random vectors

Tags: probability, random-variables

I am studying random vectors of length $n$ for which each element is an i.i.d Bernolli random variable with probability $\frac{1}{2}$. I think that many useful and interesting theorems can be proved for such random vectors and random vector spaces (like random graphs). Does anyone know a good reference which studies the statistical properties of such random vectors and vector spaces?

Comment: This isn't really about random matrices.  We're going to need to know more about exactly what you're looking for, as it stands what you're asking for is too broad and vague.  Random vectors are just n-variate random variables and they are basically studied everywhere in probability and statistics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Random binary matrices have proven applications in Coding Theory, Information Theory and Cryptography.

In coding theory, Random Linear Coding is about considering such matrices and has strong connections with random graphs. One interesting report can be found [here](http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~cvs/coding/random_report.pdf). Most of the modern coding theory, i.e., Low Density Parity Check (LDPC) codes and fountain codes are basically based on studying random binary matrices. MacKay has a very interesting paper about fountain codes that can be found [here](https://www.ma.utexas.edu/users/voloch/Homework/MacKay05.pdf).

The most important theorems in Information Theory are based on considering random matrices with large (infinity in limit) dimensions. These can be found either in the seminal paper of Shannon entitled "A Mathematical Theory of Communications" or in the very nice book of Cover and Thomas named "Elements of Information Theory."